# How do I load an image from another page using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I read that you can load an image from another page with the `load` method.

For example: `$("#result").load(url, 'tag.attribute')`

However I need to get the path of the first image from a list on another page and put it in an `<img>` tag of my code to show it. 
I am not able to do it using jQuery (the CDN is in `index.html`). How can this my code below work? Can you do this with pure JavaScript to use with React?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

/* global $ */

class GetImage extends Component {
state = {
    loaded: false
}
image = () => {

    const url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=exemple&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin8pXtzu3fAhXKlZAKHQ3dBAcQ_AUIDigB&biw=1536&bih=558'
    $("#content").load(url, 'div.data-ri===0.img.src')
    this.setState({loaded: true})

}
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loaded && <img id='content'></img>}
            <button type='button' onClick={this.image}></button>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just copy the img Link from the other website and put it into   img src=""  on your website?

Comment: because I'm doing a system, where the user will type the name of some object, and the system will get the first image of that object in google images, and then the link of that image will be stored in that user's database for when he loads the object, his image will appear. In url will be passed the name of object which user did write, like: `{`https://www.google.com/search?q=${name}&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin8pXtzu3fAhXKlZAKHQ3dBAcQ_AUIDigB&biw=1536&bih=558`}`